# how to use onclick event im imagebutton android

Tags: android, image, button, onclick, ontouch

I have created an image button like

```
ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ib.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private int initialX;           
    private int initialY;           
    private float initialTouchX;            
    private float initialTouchY;            

    @Override           
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             
        switch (event.getAction()) {                
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                   
                initialX = params.x;                    
                initialY = params.y;                    
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();                    
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();                    
                return true;                
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                 
                return true;                
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                   
                params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);                  
                params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);                  
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);                   
                return true;                
        }               
        return false;           
    }       
});
```

I want to use onClick event in the code.

Comment: You should really format the code before submitting the question as it is very hard to read what you've written.

Comment: Use setOnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use an ImageButton you could just use a clickable ImageView.
Then just do ImageView.setOnClickListener(...)

If you need text and the image. Then you could make a clickable RelativeLayout (with your image set as the background) with a TextView containing your text.
Then again use RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(...)